# htaccess rewrite rule for specific domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this rule that's working perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^images_designs/([^.]+)-d00([^/]+)\.png$ /image_design_watermark.php?design=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now I would just add an additional "language" variable related to the domain the htaccess is used on

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ni-dieu-ni-maitre|blablabla)\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule images_designs/([^.]+)-d00([^/]+)\.png$ /image_design_watermark.php?design=$2&language=fr [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(no-gods-no-masters|ni-dios-ni-amo)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule images_designs/([^.]+)-d00([^/]+)\.png$ /image_design_watermark.php?design=$2&language=en [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: The URL is `http://ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com`?

Comment: tested with `https://www.no-gods-no-masters.com`

Comment: Issues or questions with answer?

Comment: Please describe "it's not working"

Answer (score 1):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` includes subdomains so you should add the `www` into that.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(ni-dieu-ni-maitre|blablabla)\.com$ [NC]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(no-gods-no-masters|ni-dios-ni-amo)\.com$ [NC]
```

or you could make it looser and take off the starting anchor, `^` I'd go this route though.

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html