# Domain specific rewrite rule in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have this in my htaccess:

```
  RewriteRule /order/?$  /lang-en/order.php [QSA,L]
```

Since I have several domains pointing to this ftp account, I'd like to have domain specific rewrite rules.

The following doesn't work, but you get the idea:

```
  RewriteRule https://www.shakeplus.com/order/?$  /lang-en/order.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule https://www.shakeplus.co.uk/order/?$  /lang-gb/order.php [QSA,L]
```

I may need a RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}, but have no clue how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite rule for specific domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260186/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-specific-domain)

Comment: Thanks @vittal-pai, I couldn't find that post earlier. Create this and it works:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  www.shakeplus.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^order  /lang-en/order.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  www.shakeplus.co.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule ^order /lang-gb/order.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1):

This question does ok in search results for some queries, so worth an answer.

Match both with and without www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shakeplus\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule order/?$ /lang-en/order.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shakeplus\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule order/?$ /lang-gb/order.php [QSA,L]
```

or just match with www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shakeplus\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule order/?$ /lang-en/order.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.shakeplus\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule order/?$ /lang-gb/order.php [QSA,L]
```

You may want to do a 301 redirect which requires `[QSA,R=301,L]` in place of `[QSA,L]`